# Configuring Spotfire 7.02 Display Engine

Tags: spotfire, tibco, spotfire-analyst

I'm using an outdated Spotfire version (7.02) on a client and got stuck while trying to use an `<iframe>` element inside a Text Area.

This is the code that I used:

```
<iframe src="http://my.address.here.com"  STYLE='width:90%; height:90%;'>
```

For some reason, instead of embedding the page in the dashboard, it just shows a blank space in the Text Area and automatically opens a new window/tab on my default browser with the address inside the src.

**Spotfire 7.02**
[image: Text area with white iframe placeholder on the left and popup on the right - Spotfire 7.02]

I tried the same code on Spotfire 7.11 and it worked perfectly.

**Spotfire 7.11**
[image: Spotfire 7.11 working]

Diving deeper in my research, I've found out that Spotfire 7.02 uses Internet Explorer 7 display engine, while 7.11 uses Chromium 60.

Even with Internet Explorer 7, it should be possible to use the  without any issues.

Is there any way to check the display engine configurations for Spotfire 7.02 or even (long shot here) updating "just" the display engine for it?

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you enabled the Development option under Tools, and used Developer Tools to see details on whats going on? I haven't used that old of a version of Spotfire. Does it even have the option to enable Development Tools? It would be under Tools > Options > Application ? Show Development Menu. At least on 7.9 and up (the versions I have used)

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the "Show Development Menu" is only available from version 7.5 onwards (when Spotfire moved to Chromium).

Comment: Did IE itself capture any error messages in its console?

Comment: Unfortunately, no error messages :(